# Background color overlaps tab buttons

Tags: android-studio, background, tabs, tabwidget

If i set a background color, the tab buttons disappear. Actually they are visible for a sec, only during the time you press them.
Tryed to to set an small black image (looping), istead of "#000000" as background. Tryed to set the theme background through the styles.xml, didn't work. Tryed to set background color on "part by part" on the elements and leave the tabwidget alone. Did't work. Tryed move the Widget outside the parent ScrollView and color the ScrollView, didn't work.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
[...]

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paper_icon));
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        host.addTab(spec);

        spec = host.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        spec.setIndicator("Second Tab", null);
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        host.addTab(spec);

        spec = host.newTabSpec("Third Tab");
        spec.setIndicator("Third Tab");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        host.addTab(spec);

        spec = host.newTabSpec("Fourth Tab");
        spec.setIndicator("Fourth Tab");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        host.addTab(spec);

}
[...]
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/black_back"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_logo"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

            <TabHost
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tabHost"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <include layout="@layout/paper"/>
                            </TableLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <include layout="@layout/site"/>
                            </TableLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <include layout="@layout/athletic"/>
                            </TableLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab4"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <include layout="@layout/international"/>
                            </TableLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

After test other background colors, found out that the text is black. That's the only reason it is not visible in front of the black background.

... aaaaand i feel stupid again!